# Append string to DOM in runtime and remove it after X seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

im trying to append some strings to a section and want each string to be removed from the DOM after x seconds. What is wrong with my code?

for example:

JS and HTML:

```js
var strings= ['one', 'two', 'three'];
var removeAfter = 0;
for(i in strings){
  removeAfter += 5;
  $('#stringsHolder').append(strings[i]);
  setTimeout(function(){
    $("#stringsHolder").last().remove();
  }, removeAfter);  
}
```

```html
<section id="stringsHolder">
```

Comment: For a start, your element has ID `stringHolder`, but you're trying to use `stringsHolder` (note that second s) in your code. Your understanding/usage of what `.last()` does is incorrect, go back and read the documentation (again). Then, you're appending the most recent string (so it will be the last text node child element), but when your timeout fires you're removing the last one; that means you'll remove the most recently added, rather than the first added, string - that seems to be the opposite of what you're saying you want (though I may be misunderstanding).

Comment: @AnthonyGrist It is just a copy mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your id is not correct in html `stringHolder` but in js `stringsHolder`, thanks to  @Anthony Grist

```
var strings = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
var removeAfter = 0;
for (i in strings) {
    $('#stringHolder').append("<div>" + strings[i] + "</div>");
    removeAfter += 500;
    (function (removeAfter) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#stringHolder").children().last().remove();
        }, removeAfter);
    })(removeAfter);
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vb1szd8n/2/)**

Comment: Thank you for this quick solution. I accidently used sedonds instesd milliseconds. I dont understand why do i need to append strings inside a <div> element, Strings are text nodes and so considered as objects..

Comment: @user4440845 Most jQuery functions don't select text nodes. There are ways to work around that, but it's just a lot easier to wrap each of them in a containing element like a `<span>` or `<div>`.

Answer (score 0):

A few errors here.

1. You use `stringHolder` in the HTML and `stringsHolder` in the JS.
2. 5 milliseconds is very short.

The bigger problems:

3. You append a string, not an element.
4. You remove the `stringHolder` element itself.

To solve 3, instead of `.append(strings[i])` you should do `.append('<span>' + strings[i])` or something like that, so that it gets wrapped in an element. (Though this might not be your actual code.)

To solve 4, you need to select children of the element: `$("#stringsHolder").children().last().remove();`

```js
var strings = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
var removeAfter = 0;
for (i in strings) {
  removeAfter += 500;
  $('#stringsHolder').append('<span>' + strings[i]);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#stringsHolder").children().last().remove();
  }, removeAfter);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="stringsHolder"></section>
```